# How to use a Toolbar without support/appcompact library, if my minSdkVersion=21?

Tags: android, toolbar

All the answers/tutorials available in internet are about using a Toolbar with support library (for backward compatibility) And I could not find a single tutorial/answer in internet for ...

"How to use Android Toolbar without support/appcompact library, if my **minSdkVersion=21**"

Comment: Roughly speaking, follow those answers/tutorials, but use `android.widget.Toolbar` instead of the `android.support.v7` one. Otherwise, please ask specific questions about what you need to know about using `android.widget.Toolbar`.

Comment: As we know Toolbar widget is introduced in API 21. So we can use Toolbar as a widget in our application. I need help, to create and use the Toolbar without using the support library because my minSdkVersion=21

Comment: That question is *very broad*. You will have much better luck on Stack Overflow if you ask focused questions, ones that can be answered in a paragraph or two.